# multicastSocket doesn't receive packets

Tags: java, multicast

I am working on a simple audio streamer with multicast. I wrote serer and client on the same machine, so I worked with localhost and multicast-groups. The system works on one machine but when I tried to use another PC as the server, I can't get them to connect. Here is the situation:

The client first knocks on a tcp-server which lets the client know the multicasting-group IP an port. After this, the client starts listining to the address via `multicastSocket.receive();`.

Here are the important bits from the system:
(I left out the exceptions and other non-important stuff in the following code)

**Server**
Important to know is that the "LAN-Connection" is the name of my network interface on the servers system.

```java
int multicastPort = 8888;
InetAddress multicastIP = InetAddress.getbyName("228.5.6.7");
InetSocketAddress multicastAddress = new inetSocketAddress( multicastIP, multicastPort );
NetworkInterface multicastInterface = NetworkInterface.getByName( "LAN-Connection" );
MulticastSocket multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket( multicastPort );
multicastSocket.joinGroup( multicastAddress, multicastIP);

while(true) {
    byte [] buffer = audioIn.readBytes();
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, multicastIP, multicastPort);

    multicastSocket.send(packet );
}
```

**Client**
The client requests the multicast-IP and Port from the server. (a tcp-server-thread handles this) Like with the server "LAN-Connection" is the name of the clients network interface.

```java
int multicastPort = server.request("port");
String multicastIP_String = server.request("IP");
InetAddress multicastIP = InetAddress.getbyName(multicastIP_String );
InetSocketAddress multicastAddress = new inetSocketAddress( multicastIP, multicastPort );
NetworkInterface multicastInterface = NetworkInterface.getByName( "LAN-Connection" );
MulticastSocket multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket( multicastPort );
multicastSocket.joinGroup( multicastAddress, multicastIP);

while(true) {
    byte [] buffer = new byte[2048]; 
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    multicastSocket.receive(packet);
}
```

The TCP connection for requesting / sending the multicast IP and port works. An application called CurrPorts also tells me, that the correct ports get reserved, however, with wireshark, I can't find any packets sended / received neither on the clients system nor the server system. (I watched port 88 but there is no traffic,...)

Both PCs are connected to one router(D-Link DIR-635) and i guess I would have noticed If multicasting woudl be blocked by the router, right?

What am I missing? Shoudl I try  different ports or IPs or could something block the packets? I only use windows firewall and I even turned this thing off for a test.

Here is a running example. I have no problem running this on the same machine but when I run the server on my laptop in the same network, nothing works.

**Server**

```
package multicastserver;

import java.net.*;

public class MulticastServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int multicastPort = 8888;
        try {
            InetAddress multicastIP = InetAddress.getByName("228.5.6.7");
            InetSocketAddress multicastAddress = new InetSocketAddress( multicastIP, multicastPort );

            NetworkInterface multicastInterface = NetworkInterface.getByName( "LAN-Verbindung" );
            MulticastSocket multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket( multicastPort );
            multicastSocket.joinGroup(multicastAddress, multicastInterface);

            int counter = 0;
            while(true) {
                String message = "This is server, packet nr. " + counter;
                counter++;
                byte [] buffer = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, multicastIP, multicastPort);
                multicastSocket.send(packet);
                System.out.println("Sended:   " + message);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
package multicastclient;

import java.net.*;

public class MulticastClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int multicastPort = 8888;
        try {
            InetAddress multicastIP = InetAddress.getByName("228.5.6.7");
            InetSocketAddress multicastAddress = new InetSocketAddress( multicastIP, multicastPort );

            NetworkInterface multicastInterface = NetworkInterface.getByName( "LAN-Verbindung" );
            MulticastSocket multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket( multicastPort );
            multicastSocket.joinGroup(multicastAddress, multicastInterface);


            while(true) {    
                byte [] buffer = new byte[40];

                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                multicastSocket.receive(packet);
                buffer = packet.getData();
                String message = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println("Received:   " + message);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would definitely check the router config to make sure that multicasting is not blocked - specifically on the port you are using.

Comment: Are there ports which are never blocked? (I will check soon)

Comment: Does the router even have to be told that he should route these packets? Since both PCs are in the subnet, I don't think the router filters something.

Comment: There is no such thing as a MulticastingSocket in the JDK, nor a joinGroup() method with those arguments. Please post the real code.

Comment: Sorry, a typo. 
I ment "MulticastSocket"
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html

Comment: Don't type code in here. Copy and paste it. There are still errors. It doesn't compile. Please *paste* the code.

Comment: I had some more typos (joinGroup needed the interface of curse, not the IP twice :D)

But this is more or less copy and past back into netbeans and fix some typos. ;D Same result, I can run it on one machine but when I seperate the two (adjusting the interface name) it doesn't receive / send packets.

Comment: The sender doesn't need to join the group or use a `MulticastSocket.` This is still not the real code.